# Adding extra data in a Serialized control content as comment

Tags: c#, serialization, append

In my C# WinForms I have a treeview and I save the content of the TreeView as a serialized file. Here is my code:

**Serialize and save**

```
List<TreeNode> treeNode = new List<TreeNode>();

foreach (TreeNode node in treeViewFiles.Nodes)
{
    treeNode.Add(node);
}

//Serialize az binary
using (Stream file = File.Open(saveList.FileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(); bf.Serialize(file, treeNode);
}
```

**DeSerialize and load**

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

object obj = bf.Deserialize(file); //file is path to file (came from openfiledialog
TreeNode[] nodeList = (obj as IEnumerable<TreeNode>).ToArray();

//Add nodes to tree
treeViewFiles.Nodes.AddRange(nodeList);
```

**Question**

So I now have a nice save and load function, But what I need is to append some other data to the same file. For example I want to add some strings to the same file and when they are loaded, a messagebox will popup and says for example name of the user who has saved this file, and some other things. Would it be possible? Any tips and codes are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about it the wrong way. Instead of trying to add annotations to the serialised file just create a new serialisable class with the extra info you need which encapsulates the data you want to serialise and then serialise that.

For example

```
public class SavedData<T>{
  private List<T> _nodes;
  private DateTime _saveTime;

  public List<T> Nodes{
    get{ return _nodes;}
  }

  public DateTime SaveTime{
    get{return _saveTime;}
  }

  public SavedData(List<T> nodes, string savedBy){
    _nodes = nodes;
    _savedBy = savedBy;
    _saveTime = DateTime.Now;
  }
}
```

Then instead of saving treenode save a SavedData

```
BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter(); bf.Serialize(file, new SavedData<TreeNode>(treeNode));
```

I haven't tried to compile any of that but it's probably mostly right....

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah I think I was thinking in wrong way! I will try this soon. For the moment can you tell what is that underscore before fields?

Comment: It's just the coding standard we use at work - it denotes private fields. It's justa  quick way of knowing what you are working with is private to the class.